# Do I need some special requirements for installing Django celery

Tags: django, celery

I am very new to django and celery. I was reading their docs but I have problems with understanding them.

They have this code in their docs:

```
BROKER_BACKEND = "djkombu.transport.DatabaseTransport"
#celery
BROKER_HOST = "localhost"
BROKER_PORT = 5672
BROKER_USER = "guest"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "guest"
BROKER_VHOST = "/"
```

Now which host, username and password should I enter there? Should it be the VPS host details, database details, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be the settings for the message broker that celery will use. You will therefore need to install and run a message broker first, e.g. [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

In fact, you might want to read the [docs for celery](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html) first. Once you know how to get `celery` running, the answer to your question will be obvious.

Good luck.